# SQL joining and comparing

Tags: mysql, oracle

I don't really understand what this SQL query is doing. My lecturer explained that it finds the movie that is not the shortest. Can someone just run me through how this happens.

My way of thinking is, there are two movie relations:

- movie - m1
- movie - m2

How can you compare the length of data that is the same? I don't understand this basic concept.

```
select distinct m1.mvID, m1.title
from movie m1 join movie m2
   on m1.length > m2.length;
```

Comment: looks to me it selects the movie with the *greater* length ?

Comment: @everyone I think a visual would be most helpful for Chris Chen here, rather than a technical paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will returns all movies, except the shortest one.

Suppose your movie table is like this:

```
movie_id | length
---------|-------
AAA      | 10
BBB      | 20
```

You are joining your movie table with itself, using two different aliases:

```
FROM movie m1 JOIN movie m2
```

here's what happens:

```
m1.id | m1.len | m2.id | m2.len | is m1.length > m2.length?
------|--------|-------|--------|--------------------------
AAA   | 10     | AAA   | 10     | No, don't return row
AAA   | 10     | BBB   | 20     | No, don't return row
BBB   | 20     | AAA   | 10     | YES RETURN THIS ROW
BBB   | 20     | BBB   | 20     | No, don't return row
```

if you have more than 2 rows, for example CCC with length 30, row CCC will be returned more than once because 30 > 20 but also 30 > 10, that's why you need to use SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: Quite a good explanation although, I'm confused about is how you the values. AAA   | 10     | BBB   | 20.

For example the join from, "movie m1 join movie m2". Doesn't this make a duplication of data? In other words would that second row be
 AAA | 20 | BBB 20. Can you please explain how you got this.

Comment: @ChristopherChin you are joining the same table "movie" twice, with two different aliases m1 and m2, this means that every row of m1 will be returned along with every row of m2, so yes it's a duplication of movie with itself. Then the ON clause will only filter rows the resulting rows where the condition is true. You can try to play with SELECT * to see what's happening

Answer (score 2):

**movie**

```
id   | length
 1       10
 2       20
```

Since the length of `movie(id=1)` is not greater than any other movie, so `movie(id=1)` will not appear in result set.

This query is basically to select movies except the shortest one, because the shortest one's length cannot be greater than any other movies. Besides the shortest movie, the rest of movies will be in result, because their length are greater than the shortest one.

Comment: Good and simple answer. Very succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, this is performing a self-join, so that every record in `movie` aliased as `m1` is joined with every record in `movie` as `m2` where the length of the second is shorter. The `DISTINCT` removes duplicates.

For example, imagine you had the following records in `movie`:

```
Movie 1      30 minutes
Movie 2      35 minutes
Movie 3      40 minutes
```

You would get `Movie 2` and `Movie 3` in the results, but not `Movie 1`, as there is no shorter movie to `JOIN` to. Without the `DISTINCT`, you would actually get `Movie 2` once (joined to `Movie 1`) and `Movie 3` twice (joined to both `Movie 1` and `Movie 2`)

This is actually rather inefficient, and a better way of writing this would be:

```
SELECT m1.mvID, m1.title
FROM   movie m1
WHERE  m1.mvID NOT IN (
           SELECT TOP 1 m2.mvID
           FROM   movie m2
           ORDER BY m2.length)
```

Comment: Perfect explanation and you beat me to it.